# Logstash don't send data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Yesterday I've configured a logstash file, to send the data to elasticsearch.
Today, I'm trying to do the same but (configure another file) but it doesn't work!
Why? what should I do?

The terminal just shows me that the pipeline started and pipeslines running that' all.

this is the configuration:

```
input{
    file{
        path =>"C:\Users\GeeksData\Desktop\ElasticSerach\GENERIC_FUFR0004_20171017_173013379.SyntaxicError.txt"
        start_position =>"beginning"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index =>"helloworld3"
        document_type =>"helloworld3"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should share your configuration and write the necessary details of your setup so we can help. Second of all try and pinpoint the error, share error logs and the solutions you tried to apply.

Comment: there is no error , just when i go to visualize if the data have been loaded . i found in the index  nothing.

Comment: So if you check the /var/log/logstash folder and watch the logs, there is no error? And it seems that the elasticsearch output address is valid, but I would make extra sure and set localhost:9200 as address.

Comment: I work with windows

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstashs-log-files-in-windows/51330/5

Answer (score 0):

I've added in input plugin these line:
**sincedb_path => NUL**
know it works

Comment: i found that logstash dosen't send data if it is already sent once, but i have changed the name of the index in the configuration , normally it should resend the data

Comment: also i've noticed that the name of the index and the document_type shouldn't be uppercased

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer but I have no more problems with ingesting data using logstash :

Some important informations that you need to know if you have problems ingesting data with logstash:

1- The Name of the index,hosts and document_type need to be lowercased

2- Logstash don't reingest data that  has already been ingested  , only if you have changed something (*like the name of the index*) in the configuration file .

3- You need to create an **index pattern** in kibana and link it with the index created by elasticsearch to be able to visualize data of this index with **kibana**